# Html agility pack issue when getting title and images from external web url

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am using HTML agility DLL for getting images and title of external website link.
when I try to load title from the website. 
http://www.gettyimages.com then I getting wrong title.
I getting title "Getty Images - Unsupported browser detected "

whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to to with the Html Agility Pack. It seems that Getty Images checks your request's "User-Agent" http header and changes the title of the returned HTML.
You can try pretending to be Firefox/IE by changing the user agent to work around that or just cut it off.

See http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient for an example using WebClient to download the content.

Comment: Hello @Lucas, How to change/add user agent when send request for getting HTML contents?

Comment: I added a link to my answer that has an example on it.

Comment: I think it's even worse than that because the images links are in fact somewhat hidden in javascript code. This site is just trying to protect his content from being stolen...

Comment: OK @Simon, I added client then it works, but I get another issue in url "http://www.merry.com/merry.com/Photography/Photography.html" that also not worked. I tried to get title then it shows me => "Index of /merry.com/Photography" instead of showing "Photography A few snapshots and a little Photoshop"